# How to sync Google Spreadsheet in Android app and read rows from it

Tags: android, google-docs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have one Spreadsheet file in my Google Drive which i want to sync from an Android Application. After a successful sync I have some search criteria in my apps, I want results based on this criteria from the file which I sync. I am doing this for the first time and not getting good resources to start with.

**1) How to sync Google Drive file in Android App?**

**2) How to retrieve particular data from the Spreadsheet which i have synced?**

**Note** - I am also confused between **Google Docs API & Google Drive SDK**.

What to use in my app?

I have only one file to sync every time, not all the files. And the file is open to all with a private key.

**I have implemented some code but it's not working. Below is my spreadsheet public url which i want to sync in my android app.**

I am following steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).

[My Test Spreadsheet URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AlJeYFlqqMqrdGxOaHh3czVocmEtRlFsTDNiWno4VWc&output=html)

```
try {
    String USERNAME = "xxxxx";
    String PASSWORD = "xxxxx";

    SpreadsheetService service =
        new SpreadsheetService("Testing");
    service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

    // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
            SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
        // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
    }

    // TODO: Choose a spreadsheet more intelligently based on your
    // app's needs.
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

    // Make a request to the API to fetch information about all
    // worksheets in the spreadsheet.
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = spreadsheet.getWorksheets();

    // Iterate through each worksheet in the spreadsheet.
    for (WorksheetEntry worksheet : worksheets) {
        // Get the worksheet's title, row count, and column count.
        String title = worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText();
        int rowCount = worksheet.getRowCount();
        int colCount = worksheet.getColCount();

        // Print the fetched information to the screen for this worksheet.
        System.out.println("\t" + title + "- rows:" + rowCount + " cols: " + colCount);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please guys help me if anyone has any idea..I am looking for the suggestion...

Comment: How you managed to sync Google Drive file in Android App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. I have not added the permission and that is why it is giving me error. We need to add below permission for authorization.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: I don't remember the library which i used right now.. i have to check it from the project..give me some time i will update you.. but you can see the links above may be u will find the answer...

Comment: no actually i am trying to read one spreadsheet which is public means even if we r not logged in we can see it like u have given the link. But SpreadsheetService u r using in ur code, i can't access. So i was asking library that u must be using where this class will be present.